# Use of extra tables for separating NULL and NOT NULL values from the rest of data

Tags: database

I have:

a) **two kind of users**, **A** and **B**, which are **mutually excluded** and, for the time being, I prefer to keep them separate, and

b) **two kind of services**, **A** and **B**, which are also **mutually excluded** and, for the time being, I prefer to keep them separate, too.

**Case 1**

I put everything under the same table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_service
(
    id              bigint NOT NULL,
    user_a_id       integer,
    user_b_id       integer,
    service_a_id    smallint,
    service_b_id    smallint,
    ...
    ...
    CONSTRAINT user_service__user_check
        CHECK ((user_a_id IS NOT NULL::integer + user_b_id IS NOT NULL::integer) = 1),
    CONSTRAINT usr_service__service_check
        CHECK ((service_a_id IS NOT NULL::integer + service_b_id IS NOT NULL::integer) = 1)
    ...
);
```

**Case 2**

I create three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id              integer NOT NULL,
    user_a_id       integer,
    user_b_id       integer,

    CONSTRAINT user_check
        CHECK ((user_a_id IS NOT NULL::integer + user_b_id IS NOT NULL::integer) = 1)
);

CREATE TABLE service
(
    id              smallint NOT NULL,
    service_a_id    smallint,
    service_b_id    smallint,

    CONSTRAINT service_check
        CHECK ((service_a_id IS NOT NULL::integer + service_b_id IS NOT NULL::integer) = 1)
);

CREATE TABLE user_service
(
    id            bigint   NOT NULL,
    user_id       integer  NOT NULL,
    service_id    smallint NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

with purpose of keeping the `user_service` table free of NULL values.

**Questions:**

a) Except the obvious differences that in Case 2:
   i)  **more space**, and
   ii) **more coding** (in functions and triggers) will be required
   are there any other **technicalities**?

b) Is some **practically suggestable** or, it absolutely makes **no difference**?

Tia

Answer (score 0):

To have **minimum redundancy** and **highest normality** and more **extensiblility**:

You have two (maybe more in the future) types of Users. So you have `UserA` and `UserB` that inherited from `parentuser`. And `parentuser` can hold common fields of `UserA` and `UserB`.

```
CREATE TABLE parentuser
(
    pid  integer NOT NULL, Primary Key,
    -- maybe you wnat to use UserType attribute to know the type of userA or userB
    --common fields of all users types.
);
```

So, (in mapping inheritance to relational) I prefer to transmit `pid` of `parentuser` as foreign key to `UserA` and `UserB`. (instead of vise versa)

```
CREATE TABLE usera
(
    id              integer NOT NULL Primary Key,
    pid       integer,  -- referenced to parentid 
    -- other specific fields of UserA
);

CREATE TABLE userb
(
    id              integer NOT NULL Primary Key,
    pid       integer,  -- referenced to parentid 
    -- other specific fields of UserB
);
```

you can use the **same approach** to all types of Services.

**Therefore**: your user-service relationship can be like below:

```
CREATE TABLE parentuser_parentservice
(
    id            bigint   NOT NULL Primary Key,
    parentuser_id       integer  NOT NULL,
    parentservice_id    smallint NOT NULL,
    --...
);
```

Comment: In fact, `user_a` and `user_b` kinds have, most of the times, very little things in common. There is not any chance, in future, for another kind of user; only two. So, at first sight it may be better to keep them separate. Same is valid for services. There are only two kinds of service; no more in the future.

Comment: It is not important that have common fields or not. `parentuser` and `parentservice` are only **FACT Table strategy** in data modeling. (I said them only for extensibility). You can use my solution because of minimum redundancy and maximum normality.